# Dart testing Command line program

Tags: dart, automated-tests

Suppose I have the following program `increment.dart`,

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var input = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  print(++input);
}
```

and I want to test it similar to `expect()` from `test` package like,

```
test('Increment', () {
  expect(/*call program with input 0*/ , equals(1));
});
```

Elaborating my use case:

I use [this](https://www.codingame.com) website to practice by solving the puzzles. They do have an online IDE but it doesn't have any debugging tools and the programs use std io. So what I have to do for debugging my code locally is to replace every `stdin.readLineSync()` with hardcoded test values and then repeat for every test. I'm looking a way to automate this.(Much like how things work on their site)

Comment: You can use [`Process.start`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/Process/start.html) to spawn a process, send data to its `stdin`, and read the output from its `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion!!

Answer (score 3):

Following `@jamesdlin`'s suggestion, I looked up info about Processes and found [this](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/dart-io#interacting-with-processes) example and whipped up the following test:

```dart
@TestOn('vm')

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test('Increment 0', () async {
    final input = 0;
    final path = 'increment.dart';
    final process = await Process.start('dart', ['$path']);

    // Send input to increment.dart's stdin.
    process.stdin.writeln(input);

    final lineStream =
        process.stdout.transform(Utf8Decoder()).transform(LineSplitter());
    
    // Test output of increment.dart
    expect(
        lineStream,
        emitsInOrder([
          // Values match individual events.
          '${input + 1}',

          // By default, more events are allowed after the matcher finishes
          // matching. This asserts instead that the stream emits a done event and
          // nothing else.
          emitsDone
        ]));
  });
}
```

---

Trivia:

- [@TestOn()](https://pub.dev/packages/test#restricting-tests-to-certain-platforms)

Used to specify a Platform Selector.

- [Process.start()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-io/Process-class.html#start-a-process-with-the-start-method)

Used to run commands from the program itself like, `ls -l` (code: `Process.start('ls', ['-l'])`). First argument takes the command to be executed and second argument takes the list of arguments to be passed.

- [Testing stream](https://pub.dev/packages/test#stream-matchers)